# Delivery guarantee and automatic threading publisher/subscriber c#

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, winforms

I am Java programmer and for a project, I should start C# Windows Forms application programming.

In java we have frameworks such as dropwizard. These frameworks manage threading individually or in vertx we have event bus and with that, we can implement pub/sub and producer/consumer in an easiest way and we have delivery guarantee and automatic thread management (for each message create new thread if needed)

I should solve this problem:

```
Frame Captured By Camera, do IO, do another IO -> First DoSome Image Processing -> Show on Form Picture Box -> Second Image Processing -> Match Similar Frames And Save in Data Structure
```

each Image Processing has a lot's of computation and each Frame have its own flow frames can process simultaneously and each processing Unit can work separately.

I decided to use event-based programming in C#; after image captured an event raised by a function this event registered by First Image Processing Module and after First Image Processing Module done its work rise event to show image on Form and rise another event to pass data to Second Image Processing Unit

But I have a different problem:

1. I know captured image will be shown with delay because of first image processing unit computation time but I see a lot of lags in showing image
2. I missed some frames but I don't know why

What is the best solution to solve these problems?

Each camera frame is just a bitmap image.

I have an event `MyEvent` and I have a static int id that starts with 0 and increments when raising event.

And register 4 function to handle this event.

And print id in event handler but missing some ids in some handlers randomly

Comment: In c# events are synchronous. You must use TPL in order not to block the UI thread.
About the second point, i have no idea what frame means in your context. Show some code.

Comment: @Alex Each Camera Frame is just a Bitmap Image

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rx.Net](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) for event driven non blocking applications.

You can also consider using `async` and `await` language constructs in C#.

If you want to do Actor based programming you can use [Akka.NET](http://getakka.net/)

Comment: `TPL Dataflow` is also an option instead of `Akka.Net`